# How can I change this code to ""find the previous word"" in the text box?

Tags: vb6

when i try to make the program to find any word in the text

i used the following code to find the word and select it and find the next word but i didn't know to write the code to make "previous word"
if i have that sentence for example: " go to home ,go to school and go to home again 
... if i used the previous code to search about the word "go" this code can find the first occurrence of word "go" and select it and the next occurrence and so on...
 if i want to return to the first occurrence of the word "go" and select it ..what is the suitable code to do that??
 the code that i used :

```
Private Sub FindText(ByVal start_at As Integer)

target = Text2.Text
pos = InStr(start_at, " " & Text1.Text & " ", " " & target & " ", vbBinaryCompare)
If pos > 0 Then
    ' We found it.
    Text1.SetFocus
    TargetPosition = pos
    Text1.SelStart = TargetPosition - 1
    Text1.SelLength = Len(target)


Else
    ' We did not find it.
    MsgBox "Not found."
        'Text1.SetFocus
    End If
FindText 1          'search word in text
FindText TargetPosition + 1   ' search the next word
```

Answer (score 1):

**InStrRev Function**

Description

Returns the position of an occurrence of one string within another, from the end of string.

Syntax

```
InstrRev(stringcheck, stringmatch[, start[, compare]])
```

The InstrRev function syntax has these named arguments:

**StrReverse Function**

Description

Returns a string in which the character order of a specified string is reversed.

Syntax

```
StrReverse(expression)
```

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question i meant that if i have that sentence for example: " go to home ,go to school and go to home again ... if i used the previous code to search about the word "go" this code can find the first occurrence of word "go" and select it and the next occurrence and so on... if i want to return to the first occurrence of the word "go" and select it ..what is the suitable code to do that?????????????????????????????

Comment: You reverse the string you are searching for and reverse search your string from where your are.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text= "cat cat cat"
Search = "cat"

Pos = Instr(Text, Search)
Pos = Instr(Pos, Text, Search)

Pos = InstrRev(Text, StrReverse(Search), Len(Text) - Pos)
```

Dunno if it works but something like that.

Comment: i can't understand you answer.. if it can possible edit it to make what i want to achieve it

Comment: If searching backwards for cat you have to search for tac.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the strReverse function but it got very confusing to find the string reversed, then find the correct index in the string forward so I rewrote the answer using a function that just uses brute force to search the string.

The function takes the left of the string to be searched up to the start position because since we are searching backwards from the start we don't care about anything to the right. It then takes a substring the fragment and runs the Instr function to see if a match is found. If no match is found and the starting index of the Mid$ function is still greater that 1 the starting index is decremented by 1 and the Instr function is tried again.

```
Private Enum SearchDirection
    Forward = 0
    Backwards = 1
End Enum

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    SearchForString CInt(Text1.SelStart + Text1.SelLength), Check1.Value

End Sub

Private Sub SearchForString(ByVal vStart As Integer, Optional Direction As SearchDirection = Forward)
    Dim intIndex As Integer     ' receives return value of InStr function
    Dim intStart As Integer     ' the start parm for the Instr function
    Dim strToSearch As String   ' the string1 parm for the Instr function
    Dim strToFind As String     ' the string2 parm for the Instr function

    strToSearch = Text1.Text
    strToFind = Text2.Text
    intStart = vStart

    If Direction = Forward Then
        Text1.SelStart = Len(strToSearch)
        Text1.SelLength = 0
        If intStart >= Len(strToSearch) Or vStart = 0 Then ' reset the start and begin the search again
            intStart = 1
        End If
        intIndex = InStr(intStart, strToSearch, strToFind, vbBinaryCompare)
    Else
        intIndex = FindPrevious(vStart - Len(strToFind))
    End If

    If intIndex > 0 Then
        Text1.SelStart = intIndex - 1
        Text1.SelLength = Len(strToFind)
        Text1.SetFocus
    Else
        Text1.SelStart = Len(strToSearch)
        Text1.SelLength = 0
    End If

End Sub

Private Function FindPrevious(ByVal vStart As Integer) As Integer
    Dim strFragment As String
    Dim intStart As Integer
    Dim intIndex As Integer

    If vStart > 0 Then
        intStart = vStart
    Else
        intStart = Len(Text1.Text)
    End If

    strFragment = Left$(Text1.Text, intStart)
    Do While intStart > 1 And intIndex = 0
        intStart = intStart - 1
        intIndex = InStr(Mid$(strFragment, intStart), Text2.Text)
    Loop
    FindPrevious = intStart

End Function
```

This code depends on the SelStart property of Text1 to work. To use this example create a new project and add the code to the form1 code. This code will loop repeatedly over the string. You will need to modify it if you want to display a message instead. Error handling is left up to you.

Comment: put this code in program to test it, because i don't can test it

Comment: @Ibrahim If you want to test this code in a program create a new project and add 2 text boxes, a checkbox and a commandbutton to form1. Then copy the code above and paste it into the form. Type some text to search into Text1, and type some text to look for into Text2, then click the button. Check the checkbox to search backwards. If you don't want to do that look at how I reverse the strings and manipulate the index.

Comment: @Ibrahim I modified my answer to use a separate function to search the string for the previous match. This should be much easier to read.